# Pycharm (Django project) debugger gives an error when starting

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm, pydev

I am working on a django project and tried to run the debugger but it gives the error below which seems to be something with pydevd-pycharm. I have not seen it somewhere online or have been able to just reinstall this helper.

```
/Users/newadmin/PycharmProjects/ThreadIt/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 64748 --file /Users/newadmin/PycharmProjects/ThreadIt/manage.py runserver 8000 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 232.8660.197)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2199, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2181, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1451, in run
    self.prepare_to_run()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1339, in prepare_to_run
    self.patch_threads()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1355, in patch_threads
    patch_thread_modules()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 886, in patch_thread_modules
    patch_thread_module(t)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 849, in patch_thread_module
    _original_start_new_thread = thread_module._original_start_new_thread = thread_module.start_new_thread
AttributeError: module 'thread' has no attribute 'start_new_thread'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In the console it looks like it is out of date and is using python2's thread in stead of threading. But I don't really want to touch the source code and have not found the problem with other people when searching online.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right python interpreter configured in PyCharm for this project?

Comment: Yes, it uses python 3.9 and every package is updated

Comment: It seemed to be a problem with one of the pycharm packages.. I was able to fix it by installing the packages separately and forcing pycharm to use them.